# merge or combine pandas dataframes while summing up elements in common columns

Tags: python, pandas

Gaol is to merge two data frames while doing summation on rows in the common columns.

Data Frame1: df1

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['2001', '2001', '2001', '2002', '2002'], 'month':['01','02','03', '01','02'], 'hits':[2, 3, 5, 12, 5], 'outs': [2, 0, 2, 1, 0] })
```

Data Frame2: df2

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['2001', '2001', '2001', '2002', '2002', '2003', '2003'], 'month':['01','02','03', '01','02', '01','02'], 'hits':[2, 3, 5, 12, 5, 0, 0], 'outs': [2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 4] })
```

To keep the order of the columns:

```
important = ['year', 'month']
reordered = important + [c for c in df1.columns if c not in important]
df1 = df1[reordered]

reordered = important + [c for c in df2.columns if c not in important]
df2 = df2[reordered]
```

df1

```
   year month  hits  outs
0  2001    01     2     2
1  2001    02     3     0
2  2001    03     5     2
3  2002    01    12     1
4  2002    02     5     0


(Pdb) df2
   year month  hits  outs
0  2001    01     2     2
1  2001    02     3     0
2  2001    03     5     2
3  2002    01    12     1
4  2002    02     5     0
5  2003    01     0     1
6  2003    02     0     4
```

What I am trying to achieve is following:

```
   year month  hits  outs
0  2001    01     4     4
1  2001    02     6     0
2  2001    03    10     4
3  2002    01    24     2
4  2002    02    10     0
5  2003    01     0     1
6  2003    02     0     4
```

Notice that common column values get added.

I tried following: Using `concat` function and `merge` function

```
(Pdb) concat = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
(Pdb) concat
            hits  hits  outs
year month                  
2001 01      2.0     2     2
     02      3.0     3     0
     03      5.0     5     2
2002 01     12.0    12     1
     02      5.0     5     0
2003 01      NaN     0     1
     02      NaN     0     4
(Pdb) concat.reset_index(inplace=True)
(Pdb) concat
   year month  hits  hits  outs
0  2001    01   2.0     2     2
1  2001    02   3.0     3     0
2  2001    03   5.0     5     2
3  2002    01  12.0    12     1
4  2002    02   5.0     5     0
5  2003    01   NaN     0     1
6  2003    02   NaN     0     4


(Pdb) combined = pd.merge(df1,df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
(Pdb) combined.reset_index(inplace=True)
(Pdb) combined
   year month  hits_x  hits_y  outs
0  2001    01       2       2     2
1  2001    02       3       3     0
2  2001    03       5       5     2
3  2002    01      12      12     1
4  2002    02       5       5     0
```

How do we merge or concat while summing the common columns in a row level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***combine `pd.concat` + `groupby`***
This is a general approach that can accommodate any number of dataframes within the list

```
pd.concat(
    [df1, df2], ignore_index=True
).groupby(['year', 'month'], as_index=False).sum()

   year month  hits  outs
0  2001    01     4     4
1  2001    02     6     0
2  2001    03    10     4
3  2002    01    24     2
4  2002    02    10     0
5  2003    01     0     1
6  2003    02     0     4
```

Comment: `as_index=False` looks better.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `year` and `month` columns as index, and then use `add` which will align the row and column index for you, specify `fill_value` as 0 so that if index is missing in one of the data frame, it will use values in another data frame instead of filling the cells with `NaN`:

```
(df1.set_index(["year", "month"])
    .add(df2.set_index(["year", "month"]), fill_value = 0)
    .reset_index())
```

[image]